# WordPress - Custom Form for custom post types in back-end

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I am creating an eSports website and I want to create a bracket generator for each tournament. What I essentialy want to achieve is a custom form for each of the tournaments (post types). In that form I want to have an ability to choose how many rounds should this tournament have and be able to assign teams to any of the parts of the bracket.

I thought about doing this with custom fields but I doubt that they can be dynamic (for example, the amount of fields should increase if the tournament has more rounds than by default). They should also be simple to use for my client, so he shouldn't have to add custom fields manualy.

I decided to create a meta box with a form inside of it:

```
function add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box('peterworks-tournament-bracket', 'Peterworks Tournament Bracket', 'pworks_bracket', 'tournaments', 'side');
}

function pworks_bracket() {
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test_it" value="test" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Then I tested if data from that form is reachable inside the `wp_insert_post_data` filter. It is:

```
function modify_post_title( $data , $postarr )
{

  $data['post_title'] = $_POST['test_it'];
  return $data;
}
```

This succesfully changes the title of a post to the value of that form's input. It means that I can create a custom form and make it dynamic with JavaScript.

**My question is - is this approach correct? What are the potential problems I might be facing using this technique? Is there a better/easier way to do this?**

Comment: It can be done with advanced custom fields pro using the field type `repeater`

Comment: @andrew Repeater is a premium add-on for ACF, right now I can't expand my budget to include it.

Comment: @Pe-Ter acf is not exactly efficient plugin anyway.  Also, you don't need create a form within metabox, whole editing screen is one big form. Just outputting fields within your metabox is enough. It's also hard to tell if it's most efficient way to do things without having detailed specs for your task.

Comment: @Flyer I am just concerned about the correct course of actions. I don't want to break anything or do something that is considered improper according to WordPress Codex.

Comment: @Pe-Ter do you mean metabox output or handling variable amount of fields and all that?

Comment: @Flyer I mean, is it okay to just add fields like that and then update meta data in that filter function?

Comment: @Pe-Ter yes, though you should do nonce checks and all that as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) (code snippet by bhlarsen, class implementation, save function, validation part and render box content part about nonce). If you output form within metabox, you will have form (editing screen one) with a nested form (yours) which is simply incorrect.